# Visual studio code's terminal does not work with ng serve on latest Angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, visual-studio-code

ng serve from the command line runs successfully to create a new Angular program that exists on localhost:4200 but it does not pop up automatically on my system.

when I type ng serve in visual studio code in the terminal window, for some reason it says that scripts are disabled on my system.  This is important because it allows me to do development in the IDE and have it build automaitically.

Please help.

Any ideas or questions to further elaborate?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Type the following command in the terminal

Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser